# How Can we create a virtual wireless interface on a Wifi router (not USB/inbuilt adapter) for pentesting?

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, wireless-access-point

How can we create a virtual wifi interface on a fixed wireless router (not wifi USB adapter) which can operate in Inject/Monitor mode?

The idea is we should be able to connect to the SSID on this wifi router and then use another virtual interface set to Inject/Monitor mode for pentesting.

Is this possible or only USB based adapters can only be used when directly plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with routers that have multiple separate radios, or one advanced multi-ssid capable radio with *extremely* fast multiplexing.

Anything else will not work.

Changing modes between normal operation and scanning/injecting is done on the physical radio interface.

This means all SSIDs assigned to the same radio will be turned off while changing modes. Which could take several seconds each time. And also while scanning and/or injecting packets. And while switching back to normal mode.

Doing all this many times a second so normal wifi connections won't be affected. All on one radio. Seems very unlikely unless you run a very expensive mil-spec SDR radio.

If you have a mid- to top- tier consumer/prosumer device with more than one physical radio it could be done.

If supported by the radios, AND if the firmware, the config interface, and the hardware drivers are all flexible enough.